# Problems with mulitpliers using grep

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I have the following file

```
1:10177 rs367896724 A AC
1:10352 rs555500075 T TA
1:10616 rs376342519 CCGCCGTTGCAAAGGCGCGCCG C
1:11012 rs544419019 C G
1:11063 rs561109771 T G
1:13110 rs540538026 G A
1:13116 rs62635286 T G
1:13118 rs62028691 A G
1:13273 rs531730856 G C
1:13284 rs548333521 GT A
```

Where the last two columns can have only values [ATCG]. I want to grep all the lines where I have only a letter in the last two columns

Expected output:
I have the following file

```
1:11012 rs544419019 C G
1:11063 rs561109771 T G
1:13110 rs540538026 G A
1:13116 rs62635286 T G
1:13118 rs62028691 A G
1:13273 rs531730856 G C
```

I've tried the following but I got no results

`grep -F '[ACTG]?\s[ACTG]?$' file | head`

`grep '[ACTG]?\s[ACTG]?$' file | head`

`grep -E '.?\s.?$' file`

With the last command, I got the following:

```
1:10616 rs376342519 CCGCCGTTGCAAAGGCGCGCCG C
1:11012 rs544419019 C G
1:11063 rs561109771 T G
1:13110 rs540538026 G A
1:13116 rs62635286 T G
1:13118 rs62028691 A G
1:13273 rs531730856 G C
1:13284 rs548333521 G A
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe `awk '$3 ~ /^[ACTG]$/ && $4 ~ /^[ACTG]$/' file > newfile` will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want exactly one character in the last two columns use a leading whitespace character.  From your description it sounds like there shouldn't be any optional characters either.

`grep -E '\s.\s.$' file`

Or

`grep -E '(\s[ACTG]){2}$' file`

Either should work.

Answer (score 0):

Some like this?

```
awk '!(length($NF)>1 || length($(NF-1))>1)' file
1:11012 rs544419019 C G
1:11063 rs561109771 T G
1:13110 rs540538026 G A
1:13116 rs62635286 T G
1:13118 rs62028691 A G
1:13273 rs531730856 G C
```

Only print filed where length of last and second last field is not larger than 1.

A shorter version:

```
awk 'length($NF$(NF-1))==2' file
awk 'length($3$4)==2' file
```

To test only for `ACTG`

```
awk '$NF$(NF-1)~/^[ACTG]{2}$/' file
awk '$3$4~/^[ACTG]{2}$/' file
```

Comment: Why suggest awk when his regex was only missing the leading space?

Comment: `awk` may be a good solution if there are more complex thing to do.  I am not the only one who suggested  `awk` in this post.